# PostgreSQL Rounding issue in output

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

My numeric query output is not functioning properly with infinite decimals. The column is of the type 'numeric'. The output is fine except when the decimal can be infinite as shown below like: '1.3333333333333333'

**Query's I have tried**

1. `CAST(sum(column) as decimal(18,2)) / 60`

2. `ROUND(sum(column),2) / 60`

I've been working with MySQL for a while and these query's function properly there. I must be missing something Postgres specific.

**Output**

```
1
0
0
3
57.5
0.5
1.3333333333333333
```

Comment: Define what you mean by "functioning properly" in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use easy cast:

```
postgres=# select 4/3.0;
┌────────────────────┐
│      ?column?      │
╞════════════════════╡
│ 1.3333333333333333 │
└────────────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select (4/3.0)::numeric(30,2);
┌─────────┐
│ numeric │
╞═════════╡
│    1.33 │
└─────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tested this and it obviously works. However, it didn't work in my use case directly because I casted it before the division. Casting it after the division does work:

```ROUND(sum(column) / 60::numeric(30,2),2)```

Thanks for getting me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL does not define `round(double precision, integer)`. For reasons @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall' explains in the comments, the version of round that takes a precision is only available for `numeric`.

```
regress=> SELECT round( float8 '3.1415927', 2 );
ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist

regress=> \df *round*
                           List of functions
   Schema   |  Name  | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  
------------+--------+------------------+---------------------+--------
 pg_catalog | dround | double precision | double precision    | normal
 pg_catalog | round  | double precision | double precision    | normal
 pg_catalog | round  | numeric          | numeric             | normal
 pg_catalog | round  | numeric          | numeric, integer    | normal
(4 rows)

regress=> SELECT round( CAST(float8 '3.1415927' as numeric), 2);
 round 
-------
  3.14
(1 row)
```

(In the above, note that `float8` is just a shorthand alias for `double precision`. You can see that PostgreSQL is expanding it in the output).

You must cast the value to be rounded to `numeric` to use the two-argument form of round. Just append `::numeric` for the shorthand cast, like `round(val::numeric,2)`.